# How to find out revision history from hidden Word files

Tags: microsoft-word, history

I have a project – have been using MS Word 2003 – should have been keeping a time sheet, but didn't think I'd be spending MUCH time on this.

Now, I would like to find these so called mysterious files that are hidden in the file system (or wherever) and be able to see, if it's possible, all the times I've backed up the file (showing I've been working on it from 7-11pm, for example.)

I am using Windows XP Home Edition.

Answer (score 1):

[This KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/107686) from Microsoft might help you. But:

> AutoRecover is only effective for unplanned disruptions, such as a power outage or a crash. AutoRecover files are not designed to be saved when a logoff is scheduled or an orderly shutdown occurs.

For future use, use [this VBA script,](http://www.word.mvps.org/FAQs/MacrosVBA/SaveIncrementedFilename.htm) or Google Docs which has phenomenal revision support.